# Show that $x^3+2x=\cos x$ has exactly one solution in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

Show that $x^3+2x=\cos x$ have exactly one solution in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$.

Don't even know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edited for you. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I *hope* you'll enjoy contributing to it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x^3+2x-\cos x$. Note that roots of $f$ are solutions to your original equation. Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that it has a root in $(0,\pi)$.

Proceed by contradiction. Suppose $f$ has at least 2 roots $a,b$ in $(0,\pi )$. Apply Rolle's Theorem to deduce the existence of a $c\in (0,\pi)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. However, $f'(x)=3x^2+2+\sin x\ge 3x^2 + 1>0$, and there's the contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Show that $f(x)=x^3+2x-\cos x$ is strictly increasing in $[0,\pi/2]$.

$f'(x)=3x^2+2+\sin x>0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, because $x^2\ge 0$ and $\sin x\ge 0$.

Now show that $f(0)<0$ and $f(\pi/2)>0$. Your result follows from the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

Comment: Interval should be open.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 The question body says otherwise.

Comment: NOT strictly increasing in closed interval.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you :)

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 It is, because $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2]$.